# Two weird characters on a space ship, strange and bizarre anime short

Tags: story-identification, anime

From the early 2000s, this anime was something like The Animatrix or Cowboy Bebop. I remember one of the characters was red, a short and chubby kind of lobster-man. The other, I think, had bunny ears, it was large and tall.

I can't remember if it was a sort of extra material on some DVD. Anyone?

Comment: Does this red guy look familiar? http://i.imgur.com/jJxBWfy.png

Comment: Is it Fist Planet?

Comment: Double checked, pilots from Heavy Metal do not match: http://content9.flixster.com/photo/11/01/49/11014963_gal.jpg (obviously that's not the early 2000s)

Comment: THANKS @reconizer, and Gorchestopher H, it's in fact TRAVA FIST PLANET.
thanks to DCShannon. Honestly I didin't know how to use this site, I make the question on a ultimatun moment already hopeless, and one day after I have a completely satifactory undiscrible answer and feeling. 

THANKSS a LOT!

PD: I don't know how to finish the question or what to do, I just write in here, please let me know.

Comment: @recognizer can post an answer and you can accept it after that.

Answer (score 5):

It's  an anime OVA released by Grasshopa! and directed by Katsuhito Ishii and Takeshi Koike, ***[Trava: Fist Planet](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1980/Trava__Fist_Planet)***. The red guy is Shinkai, the big-eared guy is Trava. The characters also appear in the film *[Redline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redline_(2009_film))*.

[image: Film poster]